# N2CMS : Using Server.Transfer with contentItem page

Tags: asp.net, .net, n2cms, n2

Is it possible to use `Server.Tranfer()` method between 2 `ContentItem` Pages? I'm trying to substitute content of one with another, but `Transfer()` method throws an exception because server cannot retrieve `ContentItem` page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `Server.Transfer`, but both the source and the destination servers must be running the same version of N2 connected to the same database. Otherwise, you should use `Response.Redirect` instead.